# Why is apache2 .htaccess rewrite not working with /index/

Tags: server, apache2, php

I have been through many of the questions/answers and can't find a solution that fixes this issue. My rewrite is working (for the most part).

The following work no problem at all:

- url.com/almostAnything
- url.com/almostAnything/else/can/be/sent/to/etc/etc/
- url.com/index.
- url.com/index./

However this does not work.

- url.com/index
- url.com/index/

Using /index or /index/ i get a 404 error.

Current .htaccess file is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I have also tried:

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

It seems I'm running into something prior to my .htaccess file and I'm not sure where to look. Sorry if this is a seemingly basic question, this seems like it should be a really simple issue, I just can't seem to find it.

Possably relevent apache2.conf:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#       AllowOverride None
#       Require all granted
#</Directory>
```

Also the site is hosted in /var/www/html/subfolder and there is a virtualhost leading straight to the subfolder so it's accessable with url.com

Comment: I would say this belongs better on Unix & Linux, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my own solution finally. In case someone else comes here looking...

I had to edit the virtual host setting in the virtualhost.conf file.

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

remove last "MultiViews" and it worked.

Changed from:

```
 <Directory /var/www/html/elim/public/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
 </Directory>
```

To:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/elim/public/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
</Directory>
```